# How to add 2 Background images with div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple HTML page. Now, I'm trying to add `bg-image` / `color`. So I have this simple html tag:

```
<html>

  <style type="text/css">
    .header {
        height: 100px;
    }   

    .kontent1 {
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .kontent2 {
        height: 50px;
        margin-top: 10px;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="bgheader"></div>
  <div class="header">HEADER</div>
  <div class="kontent1"> KONTENT </div>

  <div class="bgfooter"></div>
  <div class="kontent2"> KONTENT</div>
  <div class="footer">FOOTER</div>

</html>
```

So, what I want to achieve is something like this:

[image]

How can this be achieved?

UPDATE

I'm have tried this:

```
body{

    background:
        url('<?=base_url();?>/assets/header_bg.png')no-repeat 100px -30px,
        url('<?=base_url();?>/assets/footer_bg.png')no-repeat 0px 96%;    
        background-size: contain;
        max-height:80%;    
        padding-top: 20px;
        margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

but it's not responsive, because when the page height change, the backgrounds are broken.

Comment: @HenryVarro yeah, that's what i want

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for adding 2 images in div:

```
background-image: url(image1.png), url(image2.png);
background-position: center bottom, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

You can go though the below links for better understanding:

1. http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/
2. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-color` to achieve background color and `background-image` for image as background on these containers. As you have two different containers, its better approach to background them separately instead of using background on `body` or parent `div`.

You can try something like this,

```css
.header-container, .footer-container {
   width: 200px;
   height: 200px;
   border: 2px solid black;
   text-align: center;
   text-transform: uppercase;
}

.header, .content {
  min-height: 100px;
}

.header-container {
  background-color: #DD3388;
}

.footer-container {
  background-color: #33DD44;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="header-container">
            <div class="header"> Header </div>
            <div class="content"> Content </div>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-container">
            <div class="content"> Content </div>
            <div class="footer"> Footer </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```